# EMR: Master instance failed attempting to download bootstrap action

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, hbase, bootstrapping, emr

I am trying to Install:
1) A Cluster with Spark.
2) A Cluster with Hbase.

First attempt to install add a cluster with Bootstrapping Spark succeeded but, I used SSH wrong key, so I have to redo the install with new key. Since then (from second attempt) I am getting the same error on every attempt while installing 1 and 2 above.

I am following the instructions from: https://aws.amazon.com/articles/ElasticMapReduce/4926593393724923

My command from aws CLI: 
aws emr create-cluster --name GCSpark --ami-version 3.2 --instance-type m3.xlarge --instance-count 3 --ec2-attributes KeyName=KeyPair--applications Name=Hive --bootstrap-actions Path=s3://support.elasticmapreduce/spark/install-spark

> Output from stderr.txt:
>   + python install-spark-script BA 14/10/31 22:00:45 INFO guice.EmrFSBaseModule: Consistency disabled, using
>   com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3n.S3NativeFileSystem as FileSystem
>   implementation. 14/10/31 22:00:46 INFO fs.EmrFileSystem: Using
>   com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3n.S3NativeFileSystem as filesystem
>   implementation 14/10/31 22:00:47 INFO s3n.S3NativeFileSystem: Opening
>   's3://support.elasticmapreduce/spark/1.1.0/scala-2.10.3.tgz' for
>   reading 14/10/31 22:01:06 INFO guice.EmrFSBaseModule: Consistency
>   disabled, using com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3n.S3NativeFileSystem as
>   FileSystem implementation. 14/10/31 22:01:07 INFO fs.EmrFileSystem:
>   Using com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3n.S3NativeFileSystem as filesystem
>   implementation 14/10/31 22:01:08 INFO s3n.S3NativeFileSystem: Opening
>   's3://support.elasticmapreduce/spark/1.1.0/spark-1.1.0.e.tgz' for
>   reading /bin/cp: cannot stat /usr/share/aws/emr/emr-fs/lib/: No such
>   file or directory Traceback (most recent call last): File
>   "install-spark-script", line 120, in  prepare_classpath() File
>   "install-spark-script", line 52, in prepare_classpath
>   subprocess.check_call() File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/subprocess.py",
>   line 505, in check_call raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
>   subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '' returned non-zero exit
>   status 1*

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: same problem here(trying to install spark). i guess aws just shutdown the auth or something like that.[i'm editing https://github.com/awslabs/emr-bootstrap-actions/blob/master/spark/1.1.1/install-spark-1.1.1.e.py to download necessary files from other places]

Answer (score 0):

The install error was a temporary issue at the time and fixed with a later version (1.1.0.f).

A readme of changes and notes are at https://github.com/awslabs/emr-bootstrap-actions/tree/master/spark.